# Can I use the Django ORM to join on a non-id field (like a CharField)?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I'd like to do  the following query in the Django ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM table JOIN othertable on table.nonidfield = othertable.nonidfield;
```

Is it possible using the Django ORM to join two tables on a field that is not an id field, or will I need to use a raw query?

Comment: can you show your models to help you better ?

Comment: You can use `queryset.extra()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter records based on comparison of fields in two different models/tables, you can use the [F() object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.F). It doesn't matter what kind of field it is.